# Prevent parent page scroll from anchor links to target in child element

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have a `section` in my web page that has has multiple content, so I decided to give it a fixed height and a scrollbar with `overflow-y: scroll`. In order to facilitate navigation I added a navigation bar on top of the `section` with `anchor links` to each content inside the section. My issue is whenever you click on an anchor link, the parent page scroll along with the section, witch makes the navigation bar disappear, so you have to scroll the parent page back up to find the navigation bar again.
Here's a quick example of what I mean: as you see the `body` section is scrolling to the target too when I only want the `scrollview` section to scroll. How do I fix this behavior?

Note: the smooth scroll part is not really important as of now, I included it only to show my final intentions.

```css
body{height: 100em}
#scrollviewsection
{
  background-color: white;
}
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

/* tabbar links */
#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#scrollview
{ 
  height: 40em;
  width: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
  }
#part1 {height:10em;background-color: #cc6699}
#part2 {height:10em;background-color: #e68a00}
#part3 {height:10em;background-color: #00ffff}
#part4 {height:10em;background-color: #5cd65c}
```

```html
<body>
<div style="height:10em"></div>
<section id="scrollviewsection">
        <div id="navbar">
          <a href="#part1">part1</a>
          <a href="#part2">part2</a>
          <a href="#part3">part3</a>
          <a href="#part4">part4</a>
        </div> 
   <div id="scrollview">
     <div id="part1">part1</div>
     <div style="height:10em"></div>
     <div id="part2">part2</div>
     <div style="height:10em"></div>
     <div id="part3">part3</div>
     <div style="height:10em"></div>
     <div id="part4">part4</div>
   </div>
</section>
</body>
```

**EDIT:** I tried using jquery smooth scrolling because I remembered that I can control what element to animate, now I have a whole bunch of new errors: for example when I click on part2 from part1 it scroll past the target.

```js
$('#navbar a').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('#scrollview').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100em
}

#scrollviewsection {
  background-color: white;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}


/* tabbar links */

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#scrollview {
  height: 40em;
  width: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#part1 {
  height: 10em;
  background-color: #cc6699
}

#part2 {
  height: 10em;
  background-color: #e68a00
}

#part3 {
  height: 10em;
  background-color: #00ffff
}

#part4 {
  height: 10em;
  background-color: #5cd65c
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div style="height:10em"></div>
  <section id="scrollviewsection">
    <div id="navbar">
      <a href="#part1">part1</a>
      <a href="#part2">part2</a>
      <a href="#part3">part3</a>
      <a href="#part4">part4</a>
    </div>
    <div id="scrollview">
      <div id="part1">part1</div>
      <div style="height:10em"></div>
      <div id="part2">part2</div>
      <div style="height:10em"></div>
      <div id="part3">part3</div>
      <div style="height:10em"></div>
      <div id="part4">part4</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

**Edited to allow for body scroll**

Basically what I did is set the `<body>` overflow to hidden and then gave the navbar a fixed height and the scrolling div a top margin that matches the height of the navbar to keep them adjacent to one another vertically.

Setting the height of the scrolling div (`#scrollview`) to 40em is probably not what you want in your final version, but I leave that to you. That is what causes "part4" to not show up when you scroll down in the snippet below.

```css
body{
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* or auto */
}
#scrollviewsection
{
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  height: 3em;
}

/* tabbar links */
#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#scrollview
{ 
  height: 40em;
  width: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3em;
  }
#part1 {height:10em;background-color: #cc6699;}
#part2 {height:10em;background-color: #e68a00}
#part3 {height:10em;background-color: #00ffff}
#part4 {height:10em;background-color: #5cd65c}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- <div style="height:10em"></div>-->
<section id="scrollviewsection">
        <div id="navbar">
          <a href="#part1">part1</a>
          <a href="#part2">part2</a>
          <a href="#part3">part3</a>
          <a href="#part4">part4</a>
        </div> 
   <div id="scrollview">
     <div id="part1">part1</div>
     <div style="height:10em"></div>
     <div id="part2">part2</div>
     <div style="height:10em"></div>
     <div id="part3">part3</div>
     <div style="height:10em"></div>
     <div id="part4">part4</div>
     <div style="height:10em"></div>
   </div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, the thing is I need the body to be scrollable too, because I have other sections too in the page that goes before and after the scrollviewsection section. This is what I was trying to emulate with the `div` I put before the section.

Comment: @LaureLazard - I added the ability to scroll the body as well.

Comment: which brings back the initial issue. The thing is the body should not scroll on anchor click, specially if the anchor and the target are within the same child element. fixing the nav bar is a nice bandaid but again I have other sections, with their own navbar too.